# Binary Channel with Probabilities

Tags: probability

Consider a binary channel with probabilities 
$$P(0 \ \ \text{sent})=0.5, P(1 \  \ \text{received} | 0 \ \ \text{sent})=0.7, P(0 \  \ \text{received} | 1 \ \ \text{sent})=0.4.$$
What is the probability $P(0 \ \ \text{received})$?

I am having trouble forming an expression for $P(0 \ \ \text{received})$. Does $$P(0 \ \ \text{received})=P(0 \  \ \text{received} | 0 \ \ \text{sent})P(0 \ \ \text{sent})?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to consider the case where $1$ is sent as well. By the total law of probability.

$$P(0 \ \ \text{received})=P(0 \  \ \text{received} | 0 \ \ \text{sent})P(0 \ \ \text{sent})+P(0 \  \ \text{received} | 1 \ \ \text{sent})P(1 \ \ \text{sent})$$

Comment: How can we determine $P(1 \ \ \text{sent})$? Is that just $1-P(0 \ \ \text{sent})$?

Comment: yup, it's a binary channel, it is either $0$ or $1$.